# snowflake - snowpipe azure blob - auto_ingest doesnt work

Tags: azure-blob-storage, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i've created all(as i think) as described in this article
[building-snowpipe-on-azure-blob](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-snowpipe-on-azure-blob-storage-using-azure-portal-web-ui-for-snowflake-data-warehouse-f0cdd7997250)

snowflake
azure blob storage
snowpipe

but pipe works only after run "alter pipe myPipe refresh"

data loading correctly, but auto_ingest doesn't work.

please give an advice how to find an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The refreshing pipe command fetches files directly from the stage while the auto-ingest option doesn't take the same route and consume messages from the Azure queue storage. Therefore, even if the Azure blob storage container is correct, the message could be delivered to the queue but not to Snowflake.

Solution Details: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Ingesting-new-files-with-Snowpipe-for-Azure-fails-while-refreshing-the-pipe-works